Example for type-safe Aggregator/udaf in documentation fails with "not serializable" error
I was having trouble implementing a UDAF, so decided to start from basics by copy-pasting the example in the Spark docs into Databricks.
The only modification I made was to create the dataframe in the cell rather than reading from a json file.
However, the code fails with Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

case class Employee(name: String, salary: Long)
case class Average(var sum: Long, var count: Long)

case object MyAverage extends Aggregator[Employee, Average, Double] {

  // A zero value for this aggregation. Should satisfy the property that any b + zero = b
  def zero: Average = Average(0L, 0L)
  // Combine two values to produce a new value. For performance, the function may modify `buffer`
  // and return it instead of constructing a new object
  def reduce(buffer: Average, employee: Employee): Average = {
    buffer.sum += employee.salary
    buffer.count += 1
    buffer
  }
  // Merge two intermediate values
  def merge(b1: Average, b2: Average): Average = {
    b1.sum += b2.sum
    b1.count += b2.count
    b1
  }
  // Transform the output of the reduction
  def finish(reduction: Average): Double = reduction.sum.toDouble / reduction.count
  // Specifies the Encoder for the intermediate value type
  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Average] = Encoders.product[Average]
  // Specifies the Encoder for the final output value type
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Double] = Encoders.scalaDouble
}

val arrayData = Seq(
Row("Michael", 3000L),Row("Andy", 4500L)
,Row("Justin", 3500L), Row("Berta", 4000L)
)

val arraySchema = new StructType()
      .add("name",StringType)
      .add("salary", LongType)

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayData)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,arraySchema).as[Employee]
df.show()

// +-------+------+
// |   name|salary|
// +-------+------+
// |Michael|  3000|
// |   Andy|  4500|
// | Justin|  3500|
// |  Berta|  4000|
// +-------+------+

// Convert the function to a `TypedColumn` and give it a name
val averageSalary = MyAverage.toColumn.name("average_salary")
val result = df.select(averageSalary)
result.show()
// +--------------+
// |average_salary|
// +--------------+
// |        3750.0|
// +--------------+

